# Any workaround to session timeout in high volume portal?

Tags: session, high-volume-portal

Has anyone found a workaround to this problem:

Sites Session Expired page should show the login page:

https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000XriwAAC#

It seems that it was reported 2 years ago, and we are facing it now.

thanks
Joel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was magically fixed a few days ago. I think SF put in a fix.